# Find error in columns for every dataframe in list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of dataframes stored in list **c**. I would like to find the differences between the columns, for example (actual-pred1.a, actual-pred2.a, so on) for every dataframe in list. I have 100 dataframes in a list for which I have to do the same. I have written following example data and code below to find it.

```
a<-data.frame(pred1.a=c(4,3,32,2,3), pred2.a=c(5,3,2,6,22),pred3.a=c(3,2,7,1,23),actual=c(8,9,2,6,21))
b<-data.frame(pred1.b=c(3,6,6,2,5), pred2.b=c(2,7,8,4,23),pred3.b=c(1,4,7,3,22),actual=c(9,2,1,3,25))

c<-list(a,b)

i3<-1:3
error <- list()

for (iter in 1:length(c)){
  for (i in seq_along(i3)){
    error<-sqrt(mean((c[[iter]][4]-c[[iter]][i])^2))
  }
}
```

I want error value such as error[[1]][1](error value for dataframe1:actual-pred1.a),error[[1]][2],error[[1]][3], error[[2]][1].

And is there any way to unlist? Because I have a list which contains nearly 100 dataframes.

Comment: Since `c` is the name of the "combine" function in R, it is probably a bad idea to name your data.frame c.

Comment: @G5W, I'll change it. Could you provide the solution to my problem?

Comment: `lapply(c, function(df) df$actual - df[1:3])`

Comment: Are the dataframes somehow similar? ie the names? the number of variables, etc?? If yes, then you can `rbind` them and use a group key to distinguish them

Comment: @RichScriven, Thanks for your solution. Your solution is updating the original  columns. I want separate columns for error.

Comment: @RichScriven, And when I am applying on my original list of dataframes, I am getting 0 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Making some minor changes to @RichScriven's suggestion it's easy to get the errors in separate columns, keeping the originals intact:

```
df_list <- list(a,b)

lapply(df_list, function(df) {
    errors = df$actual - df[1:3]
    colnames(errors) = paste0("err_", colnames(df)[1:3])
    cbind(df, errors)
    }
)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  pred1.a pred2.a pred3.a actual err_pred1.a err_pred2.a err_pred3.a
1       4       5       3      8           4           3           5
2       3       3       2      9           6           6           7
3      32       2       7      2         -30           0          -5
4       2       6       1      6           4           0           5
5       3      22      23     21          18          -1          -2

[[2]]
  pred1.b pred2.b pred3.b actual err_pred1.b err_pred2.b err_pred3.b
1       3       2       1      9           6           7           8
2       6       7       4      2          -4          -5          -2
3       6       8       7      1          -5          -7          -6
4       2       4       3      3           1          -1           0
5       5      23      22     25          20           2           3
```

As mentioned `c` is not a great name for a variable so I've renamed it here.

Comment: Thanks @Marius,  Actually i need to calculate the error as per given in my original post. Could you please make changes in your answers accordingly.